# How to Remember DataGridViewRow Hidden Property

Tags: .net, datagridview

My Datagridview is binded to a datatable, when user clicks on one of column header, I wrote code to sort my datatable using the DefaultView.Sort Method, then I set sorted view as my grid datasource, below is code for sorting:

```
 private void dataGridView1_ColumnHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Font f = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 8, FontStyle.Bold);
        string ColName = dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name;
        string SortDirection = string.Empty;


        foreach (DataRow drforDirection in dtSortDirection.Rows)
        {
            if (drforDirection["ColumnName"].ToString() == ColName)
            {
                SortDirection = drforDirection["Direction"].ToString();
                drforDirection["Direction"] = (SortDirection == "ASC") ? "DESC" : "ASC";
            }

        }

        tmptotalRow = null;
        dtTotals = ((DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource).Clone();

        dtTotals.Rows.Add(((DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource).Rows[0].ItemArray);
        DataTable tmpDataTable = new DataTable();


        ((DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource).Rows.RemoveAt(0);
        SortDirection = (SortDirection == "ASC") ? "DESC" : "ASC";
        ((DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource).DefaultView.Sort = ColName + " " + SortDirection;
        tmpDataTable = ((DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource).DefaultView.ToTable();
        tmpDataTable.ImportRow(dtTotals.Rows[0]);



        DataRow[] dr = tmpDataTable.Select("ItemLookupCode = 'Grand Totals'");
        DataRow newRow = tmpDataTable.NewRow();
        // We "clone" the row
        newRow.ItemArray = dr[0].ItemArray;
        // We remove the old and insert the new

        tmpDataTable.Rows.Remove(dr[0]);
        tmpDataTable.Rows.InsertAt(newRow, 0);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = tmpDataTable;

        dataGridView1.Rows[0].Frozen = true;
        dataGridView1.Rows[0].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.BurlyWood;
        dataGridView1.Rows[0].DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Black;
        dataGridView1.Rows[0].DefaultCellStyle.Font = f;
        dataGridView1.Rows[0].ReadOnly = true;
        //btnDeleteEmpty_Click(sender, e);

    }
```

I have a button on my form which Hides empty rows, empty row is a row where quantity in certain columns are not entered, the problem is that when user sort the grid, all existing hidden rows appears again.

How can I save the hidden property of rows so it would apply on new datasource.

Answer (score 1):

Add a variable to your code and store the value there.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I came up with is to add an additional column in my data table to maintain row hidden status, then in my dataview.rowfilter, I excluded hidden rows.